# Change bootstrap dropdown to hamburger icon?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to replace the top-left `Menu` word so that the hamburger shown at the bottom of the [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y616c4bg/) there in place of the word.

If you currently click on the word `Menu` you'll see it animates the hamburger and drops down the menu.

Can anyone [amend](http://jsfiddle.net/y616c4bg/) jFiddle so that the hamburger image is top-left and when clicked it drops down the menu (and let me know what changes were made)?

```
 <div class="dropdown dropdownMenu">
  <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle menu1 btnMenu" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
```

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/y616c4bg/1/) you wanted ?

Comment: Yep. Thanks. That did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there

try to replace your **Menu** button  Code

```
 <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle menu1 btnMenu" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Menu <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
```

with the bottom hamburgercode with slight modification

```
<button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htla" id='btSwitch'>
        <span>toggle menu</span>
    </button>
```

so after replacing this will be looks like this

```
  <button class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--htla" id='btSwitch' type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                          <span ></span>
                        </button>
```

So i changed the **Class** to `c-hamburger c-hamburger--htla`  and added the id **btSwitch**

here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/bnyh8dvo/)